# Write permissions on subfolder of share

Tags: windows, permissions, share

I thought my problem was easy, but it turned out to be hard, so I'll ask you guys.

What i want is the following:
I have a share: \s11288t\Scripts. 
This scripts share has the following share permissions: Everyone READ and CHANGE
This share has a number of subfolders (for example mapA and mapB). I want to give EVERYONE read (+ execute) permissions on everything, but I want to give write access to subfolders. So, Jake can have write permissions on mapA, and Carl can have write permissions on mapB).

At the scripts (folder) level I added NTFS permissions for everyone to read and list folder contents. On the subfolder (mapA) I set write permission to Jake and on mapB I set write permission to Carl on mapB.

But: both users have write access on the root AND subfolders! I was expecting writing wasnt possible on the root + writing wasnt possible for Carl on mapA.

Thanks in advance.